# how to pass arguments to PhoneGap database transaction executeSql functions

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm new to PhoneGap I'm using database and its working fine with below code

```
db = window.openDatabase("Sample", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(getDetails, transaction_error);

function transaction_error(tx, error) {
    $('#busy').hide();
    alert("Database Error: " + error);
}

function getUserDetails(tx) {
var sql = "select id, Name,  DisplayName from details where Name=Name";
    try {
        tx.executeSql(sql, [],getList_success);
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err);
    }
}

function getList_success(tx, results)
{
    var len = results.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i <len; i++)
    {
        //Some code goes here
        }
    db = null;
}
```

Now i want to use the functions `getUserDetails` and `getList_success` by passing paramenters, i tried the below code its giving error

```
db = window.openDatabase("Sample", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    getUserDetails(db);


function getUserDetails(tx) {
var sql = "select id, Name,  DisplayName from details where Name=Name";
    try {
        tx.executeSql(sql, [],getList_success);
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

the error is `TypeError:'undefined' is not a function` in the catch block, can any one help me to get through this?. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You pass to the function a db object not a transaction

Answer (score 1):

The executeSql function need 4 parameters, try this:

```
function errorCallback(err){
//show error
}
...
tx.executeSql(sql, [],getList_success,errorCallback);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are handing over a callback function to db.transaction. If you want to provide some data to the callee you have to provide this in the context of the caller by using a closure.

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Sample", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
var context = {val1: 'x', val2: 'y'};
db.transaction(function(tx){
        myfunction(tx,context);
    },
    tx_error,
    tx_success);

function myfunction(ty,context){
    tx.executeSql(query,[context.val1,context.val2],myf_success,myf_error);
}
```

Keep in mind that this happens in a new thread! So if you call db.transaction be aware that this happens concurrently to the caller. If e.g. you are calling db.transaction() from inside the success callback of a jQuery.ajax() call the ajax thread will run on and the complete callback may be executed while the transaction is still in progress.

Answer (score -1):

Look at your code:

db.transaction(getDetails, transaction_error);

getDetails!

Look at the functions you declared:

function getUserDetails(tx) {...}

function getList_success(tx, results) {....}

getDetails is not getUserDetails....

That's why you are getting the error.